# Doctrine 2 Migrations with ORM but without Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I build application what use Symfony components but jus a few. It means that I don't use integration bundles.

I'd like to use Doctrine. Currently, I have a problem with integration Doctrine ORM with Doctrine migrations.

I have installed

```
"doctrine/migrations": "^1.8",
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
"symfony/console": "^4.1"
```

and few others Symfony modules.
But I don't use standard Symfony config directories.
I've been configured `migrations.xml` and `migrations-db.php`

Entities I have in `App\Infractructure\Entities`.

Example Entity

namespace Iaso\Entities;

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @Id
    * @Column(type="integer")
    * @GeneratedValue
    */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(length=150) */
    private $email;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    private $password;

    /** @Column(length=150, name="first_name") */
    private $firstName;

    /** @Column(length=150, name="last_name") */
    private $lastName;

    /** @Column(type="datetime", name="posted_at") */
    private $postedAt;

    /** @Column(type="datetime", name="updated_by") */
    private $updatedAt;

    /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $updatedBy;

}
```

I can create an empty migration file and I can run migrations what I create manually.
I'd like to use ORM and auto migrations based on the Entity differences to current DB.

I see a few problems.

1. I can't see in console command migrations:diff and I don't know why
2. I'm sure that I need to tell migrations to know where are my entities but I don't know how. I read the doc and try to find something on the Doctrine GitHub directly in the commands. I can't find anything interesting.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The commands are part of doctrine/migrations-bundle.

Comment: It looks like Symfony bundle. And again...require Symfony structure. I use just a few modules with own directories structure. I could not found the way to show this bundle my directories where I have entities to read. Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you not using the symony kernel?

Comment: External requirements, I use a few Symfony components but I don't have kernel and standard config locations, auto build bundles.

Comment: I found that this is ORM configuration, not the migration module. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/configuration.html
I did all that is there but It looks that my file cli-config.php is not reading. I see the error method ` The helper "entityManager" is not defined.`. When I put exit or dd in this file, the program still works the same. Where should be cli-config? I tried in the console app root directory and in my project root directory. Both without effect.

Comment: I could not found solution for cli-config file but I solved porblem by create EntityManager as variable and QuestionsHelper, I added it to my cli app instance as "Set helper". And all works well.